# Reactive binding with VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to bind a class like so:

`:class="{active: favs.medium_title.fontWeight === 'bold'}"`

Except that `fontWeight` doesn't exist yet when the component is mounted.

Here's my object:

```
favs: {
    ...
    medium_title: {},
    ...
}
```

So when I add the `fontWeight` property and it's value it doesn't set the active class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `vm.$set` (as you can read [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)) to add the new property:

```
this.$set( this.favs.medium_title , 'fontWeight' , 'bold' )
```

In this way it will be reactive and changes will be detected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `fontWeight` to your `data` object and give it a default value so `fontWeight` exists on mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Because the property fontWeight ain't declared it is not reactive.Hence you will need to declare it in the declaration of object.

In this the class is binding properly on change of value in the property on button click.

```
<div id="app">
  <p :class="{active: favs.medium_title.fontWeight === 'bold'}">{{ message }}</p>
  <button @click="favs.medium_title.fontWeight = 'bold'">
  Click here
  </button>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    favs: {
    medium_title: {
        fontWeight:''
    },
        }

  }
})
```

Refer the below fiddle for the solution.
https://jsfiddle.net/xgh63uLo/

If u don't want to declare the property in advance you may use Vue.$set to set the new property with making it reactive
Check  below link
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats